# Error with Action Listener, not sure what is wrong

Tags: java

Any ideas ? line 66 is a curly bracket u will see it down below i show it with // below.
In eclipse it keeps coming up with an error and idk how to get rid of it. any ideas? Thanks!
It is write after the action listener, did i forget to close it?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class operation extends JFrame{
    private JTextField monday;
    private JTextField tuesday;
    private JTextField wednesday;
    private JTextField thursday;
    private JTextField friday;
    private JTextField saturday;
    private JTextField sunday;
    private JButton finalize;

    public operation(){
        super("Weekly Total Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        monday = new JTextField("How much you spent Monday", 20);
        monday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(monday);

        tuesday = new JTextField("How much you spent Tuesday", 20);
        tuesday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(tuesday);

        wednesday = new JTextField("How much you spent Wednesday", 20);
        wednesday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(wednesday);

        thursday = new JTextField("How much you spent Thursday", 20);
        thursday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(thursday);

        friday = new JTextField("How much you spent Friday", 20);
        friday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(friday);

        saturday = new JTextField("How much you spent Saturday", 20);
        saturday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(saturday);

        sunday = new JTextField("How much you spent Sunday", 20);
        sunday.setFont(new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(sunday);

        finalize = new JButton("Calculate!");
        add(finalize);

        finalize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                    double mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
                    double tues = Double.parseDouble(tuesday.getText());
                    double wed = Double.parseDouble(wednesday.getText());
                    double thurs = Double.parseDouble(thursday.getText());
                    double fri = Double.parseDouble(friday.getText());
                    double sat = Double.parseDouble(saturday.getText());
                    double sun = Double.parseDouble(sunday.getText());

                    private double sum = mon + tues + wed + thurs + fri + sat + sun;

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total is " + sum + "!", "Total", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

               }
        }
        //THIS IS THE ERROR^

    }



}
```

Please help! any ideas will work. I really have no idea what the deal is :(

Comment: Don't you need to put a `);` after it ?

Comment: the curly bracker comes up as an error im not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous object inside a method call - make sure you close the method call at the end:

```
finalize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           // all your stuff
       }
}); // you were missing the ");"
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is that you need to add `);` after the bracket in line 66.

Answer (score 3):

missing");"

```
finalize.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                double mon = Double.parseDouble(monday.getText());
                double tues = Double.parseDouble(tuesday.getText());
                double wed = Double.parseDouble(wednesday.getText());
                double thurs = Double.parseDouble(thursday.getText());
                double fri = Double.parseDouble(friday.getText());
                double sat = Double.parseDouble(saturday.getText());
                double sun = Double.parseDouble(sunday.getText());

                private double sum = mon + tues + wed + thurs + fri + sat + sun;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total is " + sum + "!", "Total", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

           }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not close the parenthesis that you opened with `finalize.addActionListener(`, and you are missing a semicolon.